# How to remove duplicates from a ee.List

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm creating an function to extend the `sequence` method of earthengine. My objective is to ensure that whatever the step the last item is the last one (or the first if step is negative). My rational was to add both `ini` and `end` after a sequence and remove duplicates.

If the steps are exactly fitting the extra one at the end will be removed. If mssing (e.g. `ee.List.seequence(1, 10, 3)` then the last one will be kept.

It looks like this:

```js
var ini = ee.Number(1) 
var end = ee.Number(10)
var step = ee.Number(3).toInt().max(1)
var list = ee.List.sequence(ini, end, step).add(end).add(ini).distinct().aside(print)
```

and to my surprise the result is `[1, 4, 7, 10, 10, 1]`. Why did "10" and "1" were not dropped ?

In case you need an example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/9567e48a96ca12af5ff89226d94df694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is an unfortunate side-effect of `sequence`.
The numbers produced by sequence are explicitly of type `double`.
The number you're adding to the end (`10`) is of type `integer`.

So when they're compared, they're considered different.

If you cast the end number to double before adding it, it's properly detected like in:

```js
var ini = ee.Number(1).toFloat()
var end = ee.Number(10).toFloat()
var step = ee.Number(3).toInt().max(1)
var list = ee.List.sequence(ini, end, step).add(end).add(ini).distinct()
```